Construction of $f(x) = x \pmod 2$ as an oracle function
I'm trying to conceptualise how one would implement an oracle function of f(x) = x in the context of the Deutsch-Josza Algorithm. So far I understand the basic idea of implementing trivial constant functions, but this has me stumped. Right now I'm initialising an n-bit "zero" register and a singular "one" bit which I then operate on using Hadamard gates to supply an equal superposition across all states. But then I don't know how to take the numerical representation of the "zero" register (the x value in question) and mod 2 adding it to the "one" qubit.
Also, given a more general function, is there a intuitive way to understand how to construct specific oracle functions? As right now I'm a bit stumped. Any help would be appreciated :)

Here's  a post explaining about how to construct an oracle.

Effectively, the function indicates whether its argument is odd or even. If the least significant bit is zero then the argument is even, if it is one then the argument is odd. You can implement this oracle with single CNOT gate applied on the least significant qubit as a control and output of the oracle as a target.

TL;DR: In this case, $n=1$ and the oracle can be implemented by a single CNOT gate.
The problem solved by Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm asks whether a function
\begin{equation}
f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}\tag1
\end{equation}
is constant or balanced. If the function is given by $f(x)=x$, then its domain and codomain coincide and we have $n=1$. Thus, the first register is a single qubit and the oracle is
\begin{equation}
U_f|x\rangle|y\rangle = |x\rangle|y\oplus x\rangle\tag2
\end{equation}
where $x,y\in\{0,1\}$, which we recognize as the CNOT gate. If the function is given by $f(x)=x\pmod 2$, then, as Martin Vesely pointed out in his answer, the oracle is
\begin{equation}
U_f|x_{n-1}\cdots x_1x_0\rangle|y\rangle = |x_{n-1}\cdots x_1x_0\rangle|y\oplus x_0\rangle\tag3
\end{equation}
which can be implemented using a CNOT gate from the least significant qubit of the $x$ register to the $y$ qubit.
